# Python Function as Macro's?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, function, macros

I'm in the process of converting some code from SAS to Python and was needing some tips on how to build a function that will effectively act as a macro would in SAS and run instances of the same code for a set of variables (dataframes) I pass into the function as an argument/parameters.

In the example I have a dataframe called country_extract. I then subset the dataframe based on the country code field. This results in multiple dataframes (australia_extract,england_extract and india_extract). I then need to apply a set of filters and sum the GDP for each of those dataframes. There will be 20 filters based on multiple conditions for each before I aggregate, in the example below I just list two simple filters to give an idea of how the code is currently structured.

How would I define a function to run step 2 for all the dataframes? Are there resources available I can look at some working examples? Currently I get errors I believe for the return saying there is nodata.

#1. Subset Country Dataframe into multiple dataframes

```
australia_filter = country_extract['country_code']== 'aus'

australia_extract= country_extract.where(australia_filter ,inplace = True)

england_filter= country_extract['country_code'] == 'eng'

england_extract= country_extract.where(england_filter,inplace = True)

india_filter= country_extract['country_code'] == 'ind'

india_extract= country_extract.where(india_filter,inplace = True)
```

#2. Apply filters for country type and sub-type and then aggregate GDP

```
def extract_filters(x):

    country_type_filter = x['country_type'].isin('CRTD') 


    country_sub_type_filter = x['country_sub_type'].isin('GLA') &
    x['continent'].isin('Y') &
    x['generic'].isin('Y')


   return country_total 


    country_total= [
    [1,x.loc[country_type_filter ,'GDP'].sum()],
    [2,x.loc[country_sub_type_filter ,'GDP'].sum()],
    ]

australia_gdp= extract_filters(australia_extract)
england_gdp= extract_filters(england_extract)
india_gdp= extract_filters(india_extract)
```

Basically I want the function to run for the 3 dataframes (england_extract,australia_extract and india_extract) and generate a separate list for each. How would I code this?

Comment: Python doesn't have macros, but you could use a function. As someone else has suggested in an answer, though, you should use `.groupby` here instead.

Comment: Thanks- I would actually have 20 filters that are defined by multiple conditions so the .groupby wouldn't work. I made some changes to the code - does the above function make sense to run it for each dataframe?

Comment: Functions  are first-class objects; you can pass them as arguments to other functions, define them inside other functions (where they close over the arguments to the defining function) and return them as the return value of a function.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's a very good use of Python functions. However, it looks like a good candidate for `.groupby()` and `.agg()`, which would look something like this:

```
country_extract.groupby(["country_code","country_sub_type"]).agg(sumGDP=('GDP','sum'))
```

Update: You could also save yourself some typing by doing something like

```
GPD_dict = {}
country_list = ['aus', 'eng', 'ind']
for country in country_list:
  GPD = extract_filters(country_extract[country_extract.country_code == country])
  GDP_dict[country] = GDP
```

You'll need to modify your function to `return country_totals` as well.

Comment: Thanks- I would actually have 20 filters that are defined by multiple conditions so the .groupby wouldn't work. I made some changes to the code - does the above function make sense to run it for each dataframe?

Comment: Yeah that function looks pretty good. If you can put the filters in a list and iterate over them, you can save yourself some typing the same things repeatedly. I'll edit my answer so I can put in a code block.

Comment: In this case would the return country_total come before we define the variable list country_total?